# Django - Check if arrayfield element is in a string

Tags: django, postgresql

So I want to write a query to find objects with ArrayField where the one of the element in ArrayField is in another string

For example a Book Model, containing ArrayField named 'Synonyms',

```
Book1 Synonyms : ['very good','awesome']
Book2 Synonyms : ['good','okay']
```

So what I am trying to do is, I want to do some kind of search, let say if user search for 'It was very good', so it result in Book1.

I tried to split the user search string into array, and do a loop like

```
for x in user_string.split():
   Book.objects.filter(synonyms__icontains = x)
```

It works but, IF the one of the synonyms is "Haha", and then the user search string is "Ha", it will still return that object.

What is want is the query to return object with exact element in the string. For example, if the user search containing word "good", it will return book2, but if the search containing word "very good", it will return book1

Comment: So why do you split the user query? To keep your example, the user type: "Very good"
In the loop the query will look for "very" then it will look for "good" never for "very good"

If you don't split it, the query will look for "very good' and the book 2 will not be returned

Comment: @Tartempion34 I split the user query because user might search for "I am looking for a good book"

Comment: Oh ok. In this case the split is definitly not the good idea, for 2 reasons. The first one is, as you saw, you will never have 2 words in a loop. Always one. The second problem is that you will search some words you definitly don't want to search.

I fully encourage you to use a parser with a stop words list.
A list of words that you remove from the user entry to finally have just what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search with something like `exact` lookup usage you have to try to use `contained_by` lookup.

If all of user strings must be in each synonyms array (like `AND` logical operation):

```
qs = Book.objects.all()
for synonym in user_string.split():
    qs = qs.filter(synonyms__contained_by=[synonym])
```

If any of user strings must be in each synonyms array (like `OR` logical operation):

```
qs = Book.objects.filter(synonyms__contained_by=user_string.split())
```

Comment: I tried but it doesnt work. I tried qs = Book.objects.filter(synonyms__contained_by=['very','good']), but it return empty queryset

Comment: @Hafizi  does you have a `Book(synonyms=["very", "good"])` in database?

Comment: @Hafizi Am i right, if you have the books with synonyms like `["x y", "x", "x z y", "z x"]` and user set synonyms as `["x", "y"]`, you are expect to get books `["x y", "x z y"]`?

Comment: @Hafizi  I guess the first variant in my answer (with cycle) will done it